# Akka Supervision default behavior

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to learn abour Akka supervision stratagy. When I have a code something like this below , I do get this

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

```
case object CreateChildren
case class DivideNumbers(n: Int , d:Int)
object SuperVision extends App {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("SupervisingActorSystem")
  val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ParentActor], "ParentActor")
  actor ! CreateChildren
  val child1 = actorSystem.actorSelection("/user/ParentActor/childActor")
  child1 ! DivideNumbers(4,0)

class ParentActor extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CreateChildren =>
      context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor], "childActor")
  }
}

  class ChildActor extends Actor{
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case DivideNumbers(n,d) => println(n/d)

    }
  }

  actorSystem.terminate()
}
```

But when I do not have Child Actor created and have something like this,I do not see the exception.

```
val actorSystem = ActorSystem("SupervisingActorSystem")
  val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ParentActor], "ParentActor")
  actor ! DivideNumbers(4, 2)

  class ParentActor extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case DivideNumbers(n, d) => println(n / d)
      //case DivideNumbers(n, d) => throw new Exception
      //Even this doesn't throw an exception
    }
  }

  actorSystem.terminate()
```

1. Why am I not seeing the Exceptions, am I missing something?
2. What is the reason behind this
   behavior?
3. What is a good way of handling exceptions when we have
   just 1 actor without a child ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not get the exception just because before the exception raised your actor system has been terminated, then the app exits.

Try add `Thread.sleep(1000)` before `actorSystem.terminate()`, you will see the exception.

BTW: This behavior not related with `if you use only one actor or with a child`. You get the exception if you use a child just because it is a random behavior related to time sequence.

Comment: Ah! thanks! That worked. Any comments why was there no timing issue in the 1st example?

Comment: You seldom to see it just because, `terminate` need more time kill 2 actors, it needs more time than the only one actor, so you have chance to see the exception, but don't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Figured its better to move `terminate` into `postStop` method.